# JButton Icon Change

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, imageicon

I have `JXButton[8][10](extends JButton)` which each hold an `Icon[2] IcAr`
in a `gridLayout()`.

`Icon[1]` is always the same icon while `Icon[0]` changes according to what i click.

For instance i click at `JXButton[1][3]` -> then i click at `JXButton[4][7]`
-> meaning `JXButton[4][7].setIcon(JXButton[1][3].getIcon)`.

These are the `IcAr[0]` icons that each hold at the start.

When i finish this move i need some of the icons to change to `IcAr[1]`.

When i make a move again i need now some of the icons to change back to `IcAr[0]`.

With what i have tried so far i get unexplained behaviour.
(Sometimes it works,sometimes it makes the icons null,sometimes it doesnt change the ones i need changed).

If someone is able to write a simple example on how that should be done that thinks it might help i would appreciate it.
Any insights would be helpfull too.

Comment: So, you have a custom class, with custom behaviour, to which none of us have access to the source code, which isn't working the way you want it to. How would suggest we diagnose you're issue?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
jbutton.setIcon(image);
```

Where jbutton is your jbutton and image is the new ImageIcon.